# Connection refused to MySQL on laravel and MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos, mamp

I have a laravel installation on my macos, and MAMP running mysql, i know i have all the info right in the .env file, the ports are right, the user is right, the database exists, the admin and password are right. What am i missing? i am getting this error:

```
*PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")*

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:bWFE4NsYpgdx10/8ODfLxLPJxru5bgY7m4KMg9LwHk8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=some
DB_PASSWORD=some

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Is this a question or question and answer all in one?

Comment: Are there any error code? other error messages? Please post here.

Comment: Also, I`m supposing you are masking real db,user and pwd for DB_DATABASE=database,
DB_USERNAME=some,
DB_PASSWORD=some when posting here. Or are they actual strings your using to connect?

Comment: The problem solves adding the socket of mysql in env file, look at the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551318/2616780

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is you have to assign the mysql socket from MAMP in the .env like so.

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

EDIT: i am using laravel 5.8, on previous versions you have to add the socket directly on the connections array like so:

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', <----HERE
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: Double check the `'connections' => ['mysql' => [ ... ]]` array in `config/database.php`; I don't think `unix_socket` is configured by default.

Comment: @TimLewis in the connections array, it is pointing to the an env variable, or null

Comment: Ok; must have changed in newer versions. I remember having to add that manually before.

Comment: Maybe, i am running 5,8 version