# Can't access a database in localhost even though it does exist

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to run `php artisan plugin:refresh test.profile` on an October project that I have. I am using root account and I am sure that the password is correct.

I ran the code and it said the database did not exist. So I connected to root through the command line and realized that the table was not there. I then checked php my admin and the database did appear there. I then changed my credentials in the .env file and it said that the access was denied when I ran `php artisan plugin:refresh test.profile`.

I tried to login to the new profile through the command line and it denied me the access. However, I tried logging in through the MAMP directory and it worked. The database was also there.

I believe that when I try to run `php artisan plugin:refresh test.profile` on my terminal, it does not work because it is not going through the MAMP mySql instance, if that makes sense. I tried going to MAMP's directory but that did not work either.

Sorry for the wall of text, but I'm very lost.

Comment: After changing your .env, did you restart MAMP? If not try that. Additionally, try and clear the cache using both "php artisan cache:clear" and "php artisan config:clear".

Comment: Yes I tried it and it didn't work. Thank you though

Comment: What port does the DB run on in MAMP? Is that what you have configured in laravel?

Comment: Yeah both are 3306.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551318/13178439

Comment: that didn't work either

Comment: Does `php artisan migrate:status` work?

Comment: It does not work but I think that is because I am working on an October CMS project. So there are some commands that are different from normal Laravel.

Comment: can you share your `db` config file